In my excel sheet combobox I want to filter the items according to search word but not working
I know this is a very old topic but after googling a lot I still couldn't find a working solution. I have a active x combobox in my worksheet "home" ,where the item source range is "itemlist" C2:C100. When I write "Ab" to the combobox search-text area I want that automaticaly the items starting with "Ab" are filtered and shown in the dropdown list (without extra expanding the dropdown). I have found following solution that works partial.
The items are filtered corectly but the problem is when I Write "Ab" lets say 5 items are filtered, but the item list row lenght is always 1, although I would expect 4. That means I have to scroll always to find the item.
Additionaly it seems that a second dropdown is always opened in parallel that is empty.
My vba code: (Called in sheet "Home" ComboBox1 Keyup event)
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
  Dim searchText As String
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim allItems As Variant
  Dim filteredItems As Collection
  Dim item As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  ' Set the worksheet containing the original list of items
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("itemlist")

  ' Get the search text from the ComboBox
  searchText = ComboBox1.Text

  ' Get the full list of items from a range in the worksheet
   allItems = ws.Range("C2:C100").Value 

  ' Initialize a collection to store filtered items
  Set filteredItems = New Collection

  ' Filter items based on the search text
  On Error Resume Next
  For i = 1 To UBound(allItems, 1)
    If LCase(Left(allItems(i, 1), Len(searchText))) = LCase(searchText) Then
        filteredItems.Add allItems(i, 1)
    End If
  Next i
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' Clear and update the ComboBox with the filtered items
  ComboBox1.Clear
  For Each item In filteredItems
    ComboBox1.AddItem item
  Next item

  ' Restore the user's search text in the ComboBox
  ComboBox1.Text = searchText
  ComboBox1.SelStart = Len(searchText) ' Keep the cursor at the end of the text

 ' Automatically display the dropdown list

  If filteredItems.Count > 0 Then
    ComboBox1.ListRows = WorksheetFunction.Min(filteredItems.Count, 4)        
    ComboBox1.dropDown
  End If
End Sub


I usually use a TextBox and a ListBox together to achieve this. Textbox accepts input and listbox only shows th efiltered values.

The range is hard coded: allItems = ws.Range("C2:C100").Value.
